# Portable SVN with GUI

Tags: svn, windows-xp, tortoisesvn

I don't have administrative right so what I want is to run SVN, download the PHP files from the main repository, make changes on the PHP files, and then send those changes to the main repository. That's it. What tool should I use? Will be better to have GUI but I'll use command interface if there is no GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, OK. So you want to:

- `svn checkout` a working copy,
- Perform some changes on PHP files,
- `svn commit` your changes back to repository.

So I suggest you to use Subversion command-line tools. E.g. get a standalone package of Apache Subversion command line tools at http://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/.